# Froala WYSIWYG Editor Not Appearing in Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, froala

I am running into an issue where I am loading the JS and CSS files correctly for the [Froala](http://www.froala.com/) editor,
but for some reason I believe that somewhere is the jQuery script, it is not taking my form and replacing it with the correct CSS styles.

Here is my view (#blog-editor is where I want to use the editor):

```
<html>
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
    <script src="/js/froala_editor.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <% include ../partials/header %>
    </header>

    <div class="grid grid-pad">
        <div class="col-1-1">
            <h1>Blog Create</h1>


            <form action="/admin/posts/create" method="POST">
                Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br>
                Author: 
                    <select name="author">
                        <option value="Author">Connor Phillips</option>
                    </select><br>
                Category: 
                    <select name="category">
                        <option value="Analytics/SEO/SEM">Analytics/SEO/SEM</option>
                        <option value="Advice">Advice</option>
                        <option value="Programming">Programming</option>
                        <option value="Thoughts">Thoughts</option>
                    </select><br>
                Tagline: <input type="text" maxlength="160" name="tagline"><br>
                Content:<br>
                <textarea name="content" id="blog-editor" rows="10" cols="80">

                </textarea><br>
                Tags: <input type="text" name="tags"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#blog-editor').editable()
    });
</script>

    <footer>
        <% include ../partials/footer %>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should check what error you get in JS console and start from there.

Comment: Hey @st3fan there is no error in the JS console.

Answer (score 0):

You are initialising the inline editor instead of the basic one and that's why you don't see nothing. You should use `$('#blog-editor').editable({inlineMode: false}).`

Comment: hey @st3fan, even with the inlinemode set to false, I am still seeing incorrect styles and no errors within my console.